# Find out who liked my comment

Tags: jira

Jira allows users to like and dislike comments.
Is there any way to find out who has 'voted'?

It doesn't have a mouse over, can't be clicked, inspecting doesn't show anything...

These are the buttons:
[image]

And after:
[image: like this]

Comment: Are you sure this is built-in functionality, and not something from the Marketplace? I've checked a v6.4 instance and it doesn't have comment liking/voting.

Comment: Is this [what you are looking for](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf56/likes-and-popular-content-658736959.html)?

Comment: @crazymatt that's documentation for Confluence.

Comment: @Stijn I'm not sure no but all of our comments have the thumbs up and down buttons on the far right hand side...

Comment: @crazymatt I don't think so, I've updated to show the buttons I mean and they don't look like the ones you've linked.

Comment: Its a plugin. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/info.renjithv.votecomments.jira-addon-votecomments/server/overview . You have to check the database tables and see what they are storing in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a plugin.  https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/info.renjithv.votecomments.jira-addon-votecomments/server/overview.

You have to check the database tables and see what they are storing in there. I guess they save the user who liked a comment, since you can't like a comment twice.